# Creating Index in Elasticsearch using Java API giving NoClassFoundException

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a node based client using Java API and index a JSON document.  Here's the code :

```
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.HashMap;  
import java.util.Map;  
import org.elasticsearch.action.deletebyquery.DeleteByQueryResponse;  
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;  
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.*;  
public class Els {

public static void main (String args[]){
    Els p = new Els();
    p.postElasticSearch();
}


public static Map<String, Object> putJsonDocument(String title, String content, Date postDate, String author){

        Map<String, Object> jsonDocument = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jsonDocument.put("title", title);
        jsonDocument.put("content", content);
        jsonDocument.put("postDate", postDate);
        jsonDocument.put("author", author);
        return jsonDocument;
}
Node node    = nodeBuilder().clusterName("elasticsearch").client(true).node();
Client client   = node.client();

private void postElasticSearch(){
        client.prepareIndex("testindex", "article")
                  .setSource(putJsonDocument("Example Title",
                                             "This description is so important. You dont even know!",
                                             new Date(),
                                             "J.R."))
                                             .execute().actionGet();

        node.close();}
      }
```

But when I run this code, it gives
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PatternAnalyzer**
Could anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This sounds like you don't have the lucene jar file in your classpath.

Comment: @Andrei I'm using Eclipse, and I have apache-lucene.jar added as an external jar.

Comment: It is the same Lucene version that your Elasticsearch version requires? What ES version are you using?

Comment: ES version is 1.5.2 . But how do I check Lucene version? I'm sorry if its a really basic question, I'm using it for the first time.

Comment: ES 1.5.2 uses Lucene 4.10.4. Get the jars you need from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.10.4). Note that you might need not only `lucene-core` but others as well. Just browse the maven repo and look for other jars as well, but all should be version 4.10.4

Comment: So it finally ran, after I added lot of jars. Could you please add your comment so that I can mark it. And thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: Are you running a war, with maven? I get it when the "workspace resolution" is enabled. Disable it, and fetch new dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES 1.5.2 uses Lucene 4.10.4. Get the jars you need from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.10.4). Note that you might need not only `lucene-core` but others as well. Just browse the Maven repo and look for other jars as well, but all should be version 4.10.4.